# PHP shop - unlimited tree of categories

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php / Mysql best tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure)

I'm creating a shop script and I have a little problem.
I need to create a php array of tree shop categories, for example:

my mysql table (categories):

```
'id', 'category_id', 'parentCategory_id'  
1, 11, 0  
2, 12, 0  
3, 13, 12  
4, 14, 12  
5, 15, 14  
6, 16, 0
```

if `parentCategory_id==0` there is no parent.  PHP array should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLJOL.jpg.

But I'm not convinced to do it with this method, so if you have any suggestion or solution please help me.

EDIT: Maybe I should display categories in xml? how I can do it? I havent any ideas...

Comment: Why are you not convinced? Your datamodel perfectly allows unlimited depth of categories. What problem(s) do you encounter?

Comment: The only change I'd suggest is using NULL instead of 0, allowing a same-table foreign key on parentCategory_ID to category_id, assuming you don't have any circular references (which would mess up your array, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As Konerak says this datamodel allows for unlimited levels of categories. What I would suggest is to drop the `id` column. The `category_id` column is the natural primary key.

Note that this holds true only if the categories are allowed to have one parent. Otherwise a separate table will be needed.