# How to find all the descendants with SQL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Each entity can have one parent. I need to find all the descendants of a given entity.

Is it possible with just SQL?

I can only think in terms of a script, and it won't be as fast as sql alone.

I'm using PHP and MS SQL Server 2005, and doctrine 2 DBAL

Comment: Do you mean you wish to find the direct first-generation descendants of each entity, or the entire tree of _n_ generations beneath an entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can use a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

```
WITH cteRecursion AS (
    SELECT PrimaryKey, 1 AS Level
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE PrimaryKey = @GivenEntity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.PrimaryKey, c.Level+1
        FROM YourTable t
            INNER JOIN cteRecursion c
                ON t.ParentKey = c.PrimaryKey
)
SELECT PrimaryKey, Level
    FROM cteRecursion
    ORDER BY Level, PrimaryKey;
```

Comment: Wow this is neat, thanks. But I don't understand the @GivenEntity part, what does it mean? Sorry, I'm new to this

Comment: @HappyDeveloper In your question, you said "I need to find all the descendants of a given entity", so `@GivenEntity` is the variable representing the value for the entity whose descendants you wish to find.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will run one SQL statement at a time so you will need to create this list in a loop. A good alternative is to use [nested sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure/5916536#5916536).

Comment: I'm not using the ORM, only the DBAL. Can I still use this? I'll read it anyway, thanks

Comment: You can run a single SQL statement, if the SQL statement is recursive (like a CTE) or loops.