# looping php mysql query till no result found

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this mysql query that i want to loop till there is no more result found in the table,

```
$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

}
```

and what i want is loop the same query again and again like this:

```
$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

}
}
```

this last code will loop the query twice but the problem i have is that i want to loop it till there is no more result found

```
$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;
```

<--! REPEAT SAME CODE IN HERE AGAIN AND AGAIN AND AGAIN -->
    }

looping 3 times:

```
$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

$sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
 $ids=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 $ids[]=$row->id;
}
 $ids=array_filter($ids);
 foreach($ids as $id){
 echo $id;

}
}
}
```

so how do i repeat the code infinite times till there is no result in the database

Comment: You want 'recursion' and 'tree structure'

Comment: No I think he wants just to fetch all rowns on that table and the code just did it once...

Comment: Yes jessica thats what i want, any way , example how to do it right?

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to represent a tree structure in your database table.  You probably need to think about your schema a little more. You should not need to recursively query a the table to get this data, but rather be able to get to the data in a single query if you have a properly designed table schema.  See these links for more information: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution using recursion:

```
function getChildIds($id, &$count) { // Note that $count is passed in as a reference (the & before the $count)
    ++$count;
    echo $id;
    $sql_query="select id from rev_r_clients WHERE parent_client_id='$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql_query);
    $ids = Array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
        if ($row->id) { // Checking for false-like values here to remove the need for array_filter
            $ids[] = $row->id;
        }
    }

    foreach ($ids as $next) { // using foreach instead of array_walk as we cannot pass a reference into array_walk without raising a warning (or fatal error, depending on PHP version)
        getChildIds($next, $count);
    }
}

$count = 0;
getChildIds($firstId, $count);
// $count now has the number of times the function was called
echo $count;
```

Note, though, that the [mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and you should instead use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: You did not echoed the id!

Comment: echo $id; is the first line of the function.

Comment: Ooh sorry, missed it... but it should be inside the if... since at least one will not have data! and you will print it anyway right?!

Comment: is there a way to count the ids echoed?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Nope, the `if ($row->id)` check ensures the function doesn't get called if the $id retrieved is null (or zero).

Comment: I can't view that link - it forwards to a register page.  When/where do you need to echo the count?  During each call to the method, or after it's all done?  Just add in `echo $count` wherever you need it.

Comment: i need to echo the count alone , can i do that?

Comment: Well, yes.  Just remove `echo $id;` from the function, and add `echo $count` after the initial function call.

Comment: Could you define "isn't counting right" please?  I'm afraid I can't see what's wrong just by looking at a page full of numbers without knowing the source data, or the code used to produce the output.  Note also that I've edited my answer to replace `array_walk` with a `foreach` (using `array_walk` may have caused counting issues as you can't pass an argument into it by reference).

Comment: perfect , that did all i want :D , Thanks 1000000 times