# Best way to create a category engine with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

i need create a category engine with PHP and MySQL/MariaDB

**Example:**

- Houses

  - House
  - Department
- Cars

  - Car

    - New

      - 0 Miles

        - Toyota

          - Yaris

            - ...
            - ...

              - ...

                - ...

                  - ...

                    - ...
            - ...

I tried creating the conventional way, but it seems inefficient.

**SQL(Table):**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) engine="MyISAM" DEFAULT auto_increment="1" ;
```

**PHP( with mysqli, pdo or mysql ):**

```
class categories
{
    /**
    *   Fetch all subs( recursive )
    */  
    public function getSubsById ($id)
    {
        $rows = array();
        $list = array();
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, parent, icon, poster, description FROM categories WHERE parent = '$id' ORDER BY id");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $row["subs"] = $this->getSubsById($row["id"]);
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    /**
    *   Fetch all parents categories
    */
    public function fetchParents ()
    {
        $rows = array();
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, parent, icon, poster, description FROM categories WHERE parent = 0 ORDER BY id");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
}
```

If you know some more efficient way please let me know what it is.

Maybe I should think about changing the database engine?

**...Deploy APC, Memcache, Cache, Json, etc is another issue...**

P.S: I want to create an online store system categories like Ebay :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model

Comment: Why do you think it is inefficient which leads you to think about changing the database engine?

Comment: I want to create an online store system categories like Ebay :)

Comment: Have a look at the nested set model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure.