# Create JSON for Fancytree from a nested set model structure

Tags: php, mysql, json, fancytree, nested-set-model

I would like to display a data structure with the jquery plugin Fancytree. After a long search in Google, it seems that the best way to store a data structure in a database is the Nested Set Model (described on Stackoverflow here [php / Mysql best tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure) ). However making the related nested JSON of such structure for display is quite difficult, I could not make it..

This consists to transform the following MySQL table :

### | category_id | name                 | lft | rgt | depth |

|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 | 0 |

|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 | 1 |

|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 | 2 |

|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 | 2 |

|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 | 2 |

|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 | 1 |

|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 | 2 |

|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 | 3 |

|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 | 2 |

|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 | 2 |

Into this JSON:

```
[{"key": "1", "title": "ELECTRONICS", "expanded": true, "children": [
    {"key": "2", "title": "TELEVISION", "expanded": true, "children": [
        {"key": "3", "title": "TUBE"},
        {"key": "4", "title": "LCD"},
        {"key": "5", "title": "PLASMA"}
    ]},
    {"key": "6", "title": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS", "expanded": true, "children": [
        {"key": "7", "title": "MP3 PLAYERS", "expanded": true, "children": [{"key": "8", "title": "FLASH"}]},
        {"key": "9", "title": "CD PLAYERS"},
        {"key": "10", "title": "2 WAY RADIOS"}
    ]}
]}]
```

I would like to know whether it exists a simple way to transform the MySQL data into a hierarchical nested JSON?
Thanks!

Comment: please have a look `http://www.techrecite.com/how-to-create-json-using-data-from-mysql-database/`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not what I need. I need to transform the MySQl table into a structured JSON that represents the various branches and leafs of my structure. The JSON should be multi-level and look like this [
    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
    {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
      {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3", myOwnAttr: "abc"},
      {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"}
    ]}
  ],

Comment: what is your sample expected output json should be ??

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? Perhaps CakePHP's Tree could help convert the same. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html - also see this link - http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Kynigos/2009/06/12/tree-sorting-component-for-jquery-s-jstree-plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that looks great although I am not using any PHP framework (PHP is mostly used for database interactions).

Comment: Seems this solution works in Javascript, but quite difficult to convert it in PHP ^^ https://stackoverflow.com/a/38512859/3994745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to make my tree working by making the JSON little by little. I do not think it is proper since it is not made of object and array, but this seems to work fine

```
 <?php 
    if (!isset($DB_connection)) { require_once('../config/_db_connect.php'); } 
    $result = $DB_connection->prepare("SELECT node.category_id, node.name, 
     (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth FROM nested_category AS node,
      nested_category AS parent WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft 
      AND parent.rgt GROUP BY node.name ORDER BY node.lft;"); 
    $result->execute(); 

    $i = 0;
    $nb_open = 0;
    $current_level = '';

    echo "[{";
    while( $line = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
    {                       
        if ($current_level == '') { $current_level = $line->depth; } 

        if ($current_level == $line->depth) { if ($i > 0) { echo " }, {"; } }
        elseif ($current_level < $line->depth) {
            echo ',  "children": [ { ';
            $nb_open = $nb_open + 1;
        }
        elseif ($current_level > $line->depth) {
            $nb_to_close = $current_level - $line->depth;
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $nb_to_close; $j++) {
                $nb_open = $nb_open - 1;
                echo " }]";
            }
            echo "}, {";
        }

        echo ' "title": "' . $line->name . '", "key": "' .
              $line->category_id . '", "expanded": true';
        $current_level = $line->depth;
        $i++;
    }

    if ($nb_open>0) { for ($i = 1; $i <= $nb_open; $i++) { echo "}]"; } }
    echo "}]";
    ?>
```