# Get half tree of category : Without using join query in mySql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get **Half Tree** of category from Category table.

#### mySql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `category` (`cat_id`, `parent_id`, `cat_name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'sadasd'),
(2, 0, 'fsdfsadf'),
(3, 1, 'fasdfasd'),
(4, 1, 'ewrwer'),
(5, 4, 'cxzxczxc'),
(6, 5, 'sadasdqwqwqw'),
(7, 2, 'sadasd');
```

### Problem:

I want to get hierarchy structure of category where `cat_id` is 1.

**Without using join query**, **use only 1 query**, **Without any php loops**

If you want to change database structure then you can change it.

I want output like this:

```
cat_id 1
 - cat_id 3
 - cat_id 4
   - cat_id 5
     - cat_id 6
```

Comment: Very specific (and odd) requirements. Can we use the letter 'e'? What about words of 3 syllables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very hard work finaly get solution of this question.

> mySql Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parentids` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `category` (`cat_id`, `parent_id`, `cat_name`, `parentids`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'sadasd', ''),
(2, 0, 'fsdfsadf', ''),
(3, 1, 'fasdfasd', '|1|'),
(4, 1, 'ewrwer', '|1|'),
(5, 4, 'cxzxczxc', '|1|,|4|'),
(6, 5, 'sadasdqwqwqw', '|1|,|4|,|5|'),
(7, 2, 'sadasd', '|2|');
```

After create this table fire above sql query.

`select * from category where parentids LIKE "%|1|%";`

Answer (score 0):

with parent/child (cat_id,parent_id) in SQL not possible. 
You have to do this with a recursive function in your Framework/Code-Area.

If you want to do this with SQL, you can try the "Nested Set Model":

[php / Mysql best tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916482/php-mysql-best-tree-structure)

Comment: sry sir, can't use recursive function.

Comment: so you going to use Nested-Sets?