# Which MySQL concept do I need to read about to query a "Collection" entity inside itself and get a Tree like result as a table?

Tags: mysql, self-referencing-table

So, I have modeled these entities:

- Feed
- Collection

Where I have these relationships:

- A **Feed** has a **Collection**, and a collection alone **(1 to 1)**
- A **Collection** may have any number of **Feeds** **(1 to N)**
- A **Collection** may have any number of **Collections** **(1 to N)**

And what I'm trying to express visually:

- Collection

  - Collection

    - Feed
  - Collection

    - Feed
    - Feed
  - Feed
  - Feed
- Collection

  - Feed
  - Feed
  - Feed

[image]

**How can I return a tree in a table result**? Or maybe this is not the right question? I know what I want, but I'm not sure what I should be reading about in order to understand this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to handle infinite loops, should a collection point to itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5916536/1405981

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen infinite loops? I don't understand how I would run into an infinite loop in this scenario. Are you suggesting I don't reference Collection to itself?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Because then how do you even plan to join?  It would require a recursive query, which can be a hassle.

Comment: Do we know the maximum depth of the tree?

Comment: Ok, you're making me question these relationships. I am in fact starting with just 1 level deep, but I know for a fact that this will need to go beyond that. If I do break the Collection to different entities (parent, child, ...) wouldn't that be even a bigger hassle to handle? I'd like to be able to insert a feed into any collection without changing the relationships.

Comment: @LajosArpad It seems very unlikely to grow past 3 levels deep (root collection not included). I may be wrong. There's an uncertainty factor here.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/